# Unit testing of BCryptPasswordEncoder hashed password

Tags: java, spring-security, junit4, password-encryption

In spring 5, I am using BCryptPasswordEncoder for password hashing. My code looks like below

```
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
```

and I am checking my code for password equals like

```
String hashedPassword = userRepository.findById(101L).orElse(null).getPassword();
assertEquals(passwordEncoder.encode("myPassword"), hashedPassword);
```

The testcase is getting failed. Does anyone have idea how to check 'assertEquals' for 'BCryptPasswordEncoder'?

Stackstrace:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<$2[a$10$EulgXiN/bEwjJZc2IqRgoOyTcJWNZp0STtgY0fZv9XSIWigMHiBN2]> but was:<$2[y$12$Q3BUtijkUb.HdXsYbS9rCuaCcQE0/VdU2YC.N18uZB7jZ4/r0DSzO]>
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
at com.home.practice.MessageControllerTest.hello(MessageControllerTest.java:172)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace, or the failure message you are getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BCryptPasswordEncoder#encode` isn't deterministic. A hash will include a random salt, so your `hashedPassword` and the subsequent `passwordEncoder.encode` won't match*.

Firstly, you probably shouldn't test the class itself. `spring-security` has [`BCryptPasswordEncoderTests.java`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/25a7482c8c5fb0ee6a08878020ea46d4f90383dc/crypto/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoderTests.java). To allow testing your use of it, use [`NoOpPasswordEncoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/NoOpPasswordEncoder.html), or a similar mock.

If you *really* want to test `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, you could change your code to use a provided `SecureRandom`, and *then* [mock that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375700/mocking-securerandomnextint), so you can control the output of `encode` in your tests.

* [`BCRYPT_SALT_LEN` is 16 bytes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/25a7482c8c5fb0ee6a08878020ea46d4f90383dc/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.java#L67), so there's a non-zero possibility that two calls use the same salt.

Answer (score 1):

The user you are getting from your repository has a different password. See the `org.junit.ComparisonFailure` message.

`passwordEncoder.encode("myPassword")` returns `$2[a$10$EulgXiN/bEwjJZc2IqRgoOyTcJWNZp0STtgY0fZv9XSIWigMHiBN2]`

while your user has `$2[y$12$Q3BUtijkUb.HdXsYbS9rCuaCcQE0/VdU2YC.N18uZB7jZ4/r0DSzO]`

Comment: Yes. I know this is comparing different strings. My question is like every time the password encoder changes the hashing value so what is the best way to check assertEquals for the same?